# ImportError: cannot import name 'TableList' from 'camelot.core'

Tags: python

i tried to extract the tables from a pdf using camelot but it is showing this error message!

```
import camelot
    tables = camelot.read_pdf("C:/Users/shres/Desktop/PY/Arun District Council_ASR-2019.pdf", pages='all')
    tables
    tables.export("test.csv", f='csv')
    tables[0]
    tables[0].parsing_report
    {
        'accuracy' : 99.02,
        'whitespace':12.24,
        'order': 1,
        'page' : 1
    }
    tables[0].to_csv('test.csv')
    tables[0].df
******error: the code shows this error******
ImportError: cannot import name 'TableList' from 'camelot.core' (C:\Users\shres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\camelot\core\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you might want to reinstall it.
Camelot and camelot-py are two different packages but they have the same import name.

```
pip uninstall camelot
pip uninstall camelot-py
pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

Comment: This fixed many dependency issues for me. I now have: `OSError: Ghostscript is not installed`. Would you know how to fix this please? @Victor I've made a post regarding it.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200091/import-camelot-oserror-ghostscript-is-not-installed

Comment: i was using google colab, this was not solving the issue, but creating the new notebook and running
!pip install camelot-py[cv]
solved the issue.

Comment: On colab, definitely !pip install camelot-py[cv] one works.

Answer (score 2):

It will also generate the same problem for me and I know that it is too late but maybe the same thing will happen to other people and as I managed to solve it, it was git cloning the repo and then inside the camelot street I installed the cv with pip install like this:

1. pip install "camelot-py [cv]"
2. git clone https://www.github.com/camelot-dev/camelot
3. cd camelot
4. pip install ".[cv]"

Answer (score 1):

While using Google Colab,
Try installing below:

```
pip uninstall camelot
pip uninstall camelot-py
pip install camelot-py[cv]

# install ghostscript
! apt install ghostscript python3-tk
! pip install ghostscript
```

Even after installation if it throws same error, try "**Restart Runtime**" in Colab and that should fix the issue! Worked for me :)