# Unable to install Camelot - receiving errors or won't stop loading

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, python-camelot

I have been trying to install camelot onto my computer to use via VS Code. I have tkinter and ghostscript installed, but I'm unable to install camelot. I accidentally ran !pip install camelot, so I'm unable to use read_pdf since it isn't the correct package.

I am using VS Code through Anaconda3 if that helps.

I've tried all of the follow, separately...

```
!pip install camelot-py
```

```
!pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

```
!pip install camelot-py[base]
```

```
!pip install "camelot-py[base]"
```

The above all result in VS Code loading forever and never finish installing anything.

I've also tried

```
conda install tabula-py[cv]
```

```
conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py
```

and it finished loading, but I get the error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated as I have been googling for hours with no resolution.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does this answer help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913882/importerror-cannot-import-name-tablelist-from-camelot-core

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87 I tried to use the solution you linked, but the the uninstall never completes. I've let it run for 30 minutes and nothing happens

Comment: I would try to run a clean installation in a new virtual environment. `python -m venv venv`; `source venv/bin/activate`; `pip install camelot-py[cv]`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing error when i was doing

> pip install camelot

But when i did..

> pip install camelot-py

Then, now it's working

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you should use 'pip install camelot-py'. Secondly, I recommend running echo $PATH to check if your Ghostscript package has been added to the path your program is referencing. The most common issue encountered typically relates to these paths. If it has not yet been set up properly or visibly you need to redirect the path and ensure your environment is aware of this change.